# How to solve this type of ODE: $4f^3f''+12f^2f'^2+3f^2f'+cf'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve this type of ODE:
>   $$4f^3f''+12f^2f'^2+3f^2f'+cf'=0$$

Comment: What do you mean by solve? Clearly $f=0$ is a solution. What have you tried yourself, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Mrtaurho any solution other than f=0??

Comment: I have tried to find the solution of this ode by maple.maple gives the following solution..   int(a^3/-a^2+ac+c1)da-x-c2

Comment: @MubashirAslam I guess you would like to refer to *Servaes* and not to me since I have no idea right now. Additionally I would suggest to you to edit your question in order to include your own attempt and what you tried since right now your post will attract downvotes aswell as close votes.

Comment: Rewrite it as $(f^4)''+(f^3+cf)'=0$

Comment: You can then write the solution on implicit form by integrating the ODE so you'll get something like $\int_{y(0)}^{y(x)}G(t)\,{\rm d}t = x$ for some function $G(t)$. If this integral is analytically solvable and the resulting equation analytically invertible is another question, very likely not.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$4f^3f''+12f^2f'^2+3f^2f'+cf'=0$

$(4f^3f')'+(f^3+cf)'=0$

$4f^3f'+f^3+cf+a=0$

$-4f^3\dfrac{df}{dx}=f^3+cf+a$

$dx=-\dfrac{4f^3}{f^3+cf+a}df$

$x=C-\int^f\dfrac{4f^3}{f^3+cf+a}df$